# Find the class from where the exception has generated. without using stacktrace and with @ControllerAdvice in AOP way

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am centralizing the exception handling in my app. But I want the messages to be internationalized and should be kept in a properties file.  For this purpose I am planning to keep the keys with fully qualified name of the controller appended with .message. So my @ControllerAdvice marked class will handle the exception and fetch the message from the properties file based on the "fully qualified name of exception.ControllerName" and the problem is I am not getting the controller name and the method signatures from where the exception occurred. Is there a way to do so??

Comment: This was reported as a feature request by me in spring. which is here : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12605?filter=-2 and will be available from spring version 4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no direct way to achieve this.

So you need to have an `Around` advice for your `@ExceptionHandler` annotated methods such as below

```
@Aspect
public class ExceptionLogging {

@Around(execution("@annotation(ExceptionHandler)"))
public Object logException(ProceddingJoinPoint pjp){
    String name = pjp.getSignature().getName(); // tweak this as per your requirement
    logger.info("Controller where Exception was raised - " + name);
    Object obj = pjp.proceed();
    return obj;
  }

}
```

Comment: @ControllerAdvice internally uses AOP right?? then why not this is available as part of it?

Comment: May be because your requirement is too specific ... you can however request this feature for Spring future releases.

Comment: My requirement is simple. I want a centralized exception hanlding for all controller level classes using ControllerAdvice, I am aware about AOP but I thought implementing this will work in same way like working with AOP. I might be wrong about the purpose of ControllerAdvice.

Comment: From `@ControllerAdvice` docs - `It is typically used to define @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, and @ModelAttribute methods that apply to all @RequestMapping methods` which clearly states its purpose. As mentioned earlier you can request this feature and if community deems it fit, it will be part of future release.

Comment: thanx for the help, This would be the link where I can request this https://jira.spring.io/ right?

Comment: here is the URL I submitted the feature request here is the link : https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12605?filter=-2 in case if you want to add anything.

Comment: It is now available as a feature in Spring from version 4.2

Comment: @BilboBaggins can you please tell how to get the class name where exception occurs with ControllerAdvice

Comment: I guess using JoinPoint.getTarget.getClass() you would get the class name.